# Stored Procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using Stored procedure to fetch data from database .

```
$result = mysql_query("call FindProspectRequests('','Summit','','NULL','NULL')") or die (mysql_error());
```

where last two parameters are starttime and endtime   If i am  calling directly as above my procedure is working .(Fields are accepting value as NULL )

But consider this scenario,
when i am calling as below it is not working for me .

```
 $starttime ='NULL';
 $endtime ='NULL';

$result = mysql_query("call FindProspectRequests('','Summit','','$starttime','$endtime')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Please tell me what might i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to do:

```
$starttime = "NULL";
$endtime = "NULL";

$result = mysql_query("call FindProspectRequests('','Summit','',$starttime,$endtime)") or die (mysql_error());
```

Note: the removed quote marks within the SQL string you are sending...

**However I do strongly urge you to heed the advice from @WaleedKhan** and cease to use the mysql_ functions and pick between mysqli and PDO... If this is an app with lots of code already switching to the mysqi_* commands will be the way to go with the least changes to make.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL'')' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
     $starttime = "'NULL'";
     $endtime = "'NULL'";
```